# in a searchDisplayController 's results, how can I highlight the string typed in in the UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a searchDisplayController, I want the results to bold out any occurrences of the string  that was typed in the search bar.

[image]

in this case, the expected behavior of the search results should have the string "Bla" in the search results highlighted(or changed to a different style - italicized etc)

I've tried looking into NSMutableAttributedString and NSAttributedString, but still a bit unsure of how to change the style of the string in the search results

Comment: Slightly off topic, but if you want to take a screenshot of a particular window such as the simulator. Press "SHIFT+CMD+4" to bring up the screenshot selection tool and then press "SPACEBAR". This will change the cursor to a camera. You can now click on any window to screengrab it in a much cleaner way.

Comment: heh nice thanks justyn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following to do what you want. It basically takes your search string and creates a regular expression which will be used to find all occurrences of the search string in the results string. We then loop through these results and change the font attribute to a bold font.

```c
NSString *searchText = @"searc";

NSString *resultsText = @"I want to highlight what I'm searching for in these search results. Searching can often…";

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:resultsText];

NSString * regexPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", searchText];

// We create a case insensitive regex passing in our pattern
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,resultsText.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:resultsText
                        options:kNilOptions
                          range:range
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];

    // Make the range bold
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                                    value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15.0]
                                    range:subStringRange];
}];

// Replace your result string with the updated attributed string
self.resultLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

This will give you something like this:
[image]